# Is it possible to use the jquery load function to open a model in the centre of the page when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried using the jquery load function in the code below to load the model (.DAE file) into a div but it doesn't work and displays a load of numbers and words as shown in the screenshot below.

[Screenshot of issue when the button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOJfR.png)

I was wondering if it is possible to use the load function to display the model (.DAE file) in the centre of the page, much like the screenshot, but switch between the two models displayed in the centre of the page when either of the buttons are clicked.(In other words is there a selector to load the model in the centre of the page rather than a div?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#LBC').click(function () {
                    $('#target').load('blood.DAE');
                });
            });
        </script>
        <title>Visualising Cells</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="three.js"></script>
        <script src="ColladaLoader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script>
            var width = window.innerWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight;
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
                75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 500
            );
            camera.position.z = 0.16;
            camera.position.x = 0;
            camera.position.y = 0;
            scene.add(camera);

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(width, height);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            renderer.setClearColor("rgb(181,181,181)");

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
            light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
            scene.add(light);

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
            light.position.set(0, 0, 0.14);
            scene.add(light);

            var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
            loader.load('blood.DAE', function (collada) {
                var object = collada.scene;
                object.position.x = 0;
                object.position.y = 0;
                object.position.z = 0;
                object.updateMatrix();
                scene.add(object);
            }
            );

            document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
                console.log("Up Arrow Pressed");
                console.log(camera.position.z);
                if (event.keyCode === 38) {
                    if (camera.position.z >= 0.1) {
                        camera.position.z = camera.position.z - 0.01;
                    }
                }

                else if (event.keyCode === 40) {

                    console.log("Down Arrow Pressed");
                    if (camera.position.z < 0.2)
                        camera.position.z = camera.position.z + 0.01;
                }
            }, true);

            render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame(render);
                object.rotation.x += 0.01;
                object.rotation.y += 0.01;
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };
            render();
        </script>

        <div class="float-btn">
            <button type="button" id="LBC">Load Red Blood Cell</button>
            <button type="button" id="LEC">Load Egg Cell</button>
        </div>

        <div class="float-txt">
            <div style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial; font-size: 18px; text-decoration: underline;">
                <h1>Visualising Microscopic Cells</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="instructions">
            <div style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: underline;">
                <h2>Instructions</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="instruction-txt">
            <div style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px">
                <p>
                    <u>Zoom In:</u> <strong>Up Arrow</strong> <br />
                    <u>Zoom Out:</u> <strong>Down Arrow</strong>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Model-Location" id="target"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `blood.dae` ajax call returns HTML...

There are more complicated schemes if you want to cache the content, but you can just have two different handlers for your two different buttons that each load the content into the target:

```
$('#LBC1').click(function() {
    $('#target').load('blood.DAE');
});

$('#LBC2').click(function() {
    $('#target').load('somethingelse.DAE');
});
```

If you expect the user to be switching back and forth and you want to make sure that is quick, you could load the content into two different targets and then hide/show the appropriate one when clicked if it was already loaded.

Comment: The `$('#target').load` is the part that isn't working correctly. The first model is loaded further down in the script.

Comment: @jfriend00 Isn't the code you suggested the same as what I used? I still have the same problem shown in the screenshot, it seems to be related to the other answer but i have no idea how to achieve what is described.

Comment: @G.Smith - `.load()` assumes the result of the Ajax call is HTML and it inserts that HTML into your page for you.  If your ajax call is not returning HTML, then you will have to either change the ajax call to fetch HTML or you will have to fetch the data with a regular Ajax call and then turn it into something that can be displayed in the web page with your Javascript.  Without knowing that the `blood.dae` call is returning, we can't really advise any more specifically.

Comment: @G.Smith - FYI, screen shots often don't mean anything to us because we don't know what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: @jfriend00 Basically, on the screenshot there is a long list of numbers on the right hand side that shouldn't be there and appear when the button is pressed to load the blood.dae file.

Comment: @G.Smith - Then apparently your problem is that what `blood.dae` is returning is not what you want displayed or you have not properly formatted it for display.  I don't know what you want us to do here to help you with that since you did not include in your question ANY of that information, context or explanation.

Comment: @G.Smith - Did this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, then please explain what you still need help with.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used a .dae file but Im assuming the page is loading up the xml from it and not actually converting it into what you want. You'll need to figure out some method of converting the data into the GUI format you want then call it to be loaded with jquery.

Comment: I'm guessing you have no idea how convert the data into the GUI format?

Comment: I would just google .dae api and see what you can find.

Comment: I've found something called a FMX.DAE Importer but i'm not sure how to download it.